# Nuget package is using a local version of a DLL in ArcGIS Pro, instead of what the package actually depends on

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, .net, add-in, dll

Problem:-
Dll mismatches.

ArcGIS Pro version 3.1 contains the DLL System.ServiceModel.Primitives Version=4.9.0.0 in its' bin folder.

My solution contains an add-in that relies on 4 projects also in the same solution, all are targeting .NET 6.0. One of those 4 projects contains a package that relies on System.ServiceModel.Primitves Version 6.0.0.0.
Now when I build the solution in Visual studio 2022 I get no errors, no warning.

When I run it however, and ArcGIS Pro starts loading, I get an exception in the add-in initialization module.

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.DuplexChannelFactory`1' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

None of my projects is loading up this assembly version, I checked the Deps.Json thoroughly, and there it is simply not there, neither is it in the output folder, only the correct version.

I went ahead and copied version 6.0 to the bin folder of ArcGIS Pro, and the issue was gone, I brought back version 4.9 to the bin folder, the problem returns.

I tried using Binding redirects in the projects app config, I tried using assembly loading techniques when the code enters the add in module to load the correct dll, and nothing seems to resolve this issue.

I have asked this question on StackOverflow  and placed a bounty, and no luck, so I decided to move the question here, since this issue seems more related to ArcGIS Pro.
I have the projects all posted in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888984/nuget-package-is-using-a-local-version-of-a-dll-instead-of-the-on-that-comes-wit?noredirect=1#comment137389207_77888984